# Toggle active class to buttons when clicked

Tags: javascript

With the current code written, I am able to select the first button with a class of mobile__CTA--btn and toggle the "active" class when clicked. When I click on the next button to try to toggle the "active" class, the first button gets the class unassigned yet I am not able to assign the "active" class to the next button. Any suggestions?

```js
const callToActionBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".mobile__CTA--btn");

callToActionBtns.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    const currentBtn =
      e.target.parentElement.querySelector(".mobile__CTA--btn");
    currentBtn.classList.toggle("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  color          : white;
  border-bottom  : 5px solid $purple;
  padding-bottom : 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile__CTA">
  <button id="overview-btn"  class="mobile__CTA--btn"> OVERVIEW </button>
  <button id="structure-btn" class="mobile__CTA--btn"> STRUCTURE </button>
  <button id="surface-btn"   class="mobile__CTA--btn"> SURFACE   </button>
</div>
```

Comment: `this.classList.toggle("active");` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```js
const currentBtn =
      e.target.parentElement.querySelector(".mobile__CTA--btn");
currentBtn.classList.toggle("active");
```

Gets the parent `div` container, finds the first element with the class `mobile__CTA--btn` (which is the first button) and toggles the class.

You should instead be looping through `callToActionBtns` and removing the class `active`, then toggling the `active` class for the event target:

```js
const callToActionBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".mobile__CTA--btn");

callToActionBtns.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    callToActionBtns.forEach(f => f.classList.remove('active'));
    e.target.classList.toggle("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 5px solid $purple;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile__CTA">
  <button id="overview-btn" class="mobile__CTA--btn">OVERVIEW</button>
  <button id="structure-btn" class="mobile__CTA--btn">STRUCTURE</button>
  <button id="surface-btn" class="mobile__CTA--btn">SURFACE</button>
</div>
```

If you want to have the ability to untoggle the current button, just add an `if` statement while looping that checks whether the item currently being looped through is the target element:

```js
const callToActionBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".mobile__CTA--btn");

callToActionBtns.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    callToActionBtns.forEach(f => f != e.target ? f.classList.remove('active') : '');
      e.target.classList.toggle("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 5px solid $purple;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile__CTA">
  <button id="overview-btn" class="mobile__CTA--btn">OVERVIEW</button>
  <button id="structure-btn" class="mobile__CTA--btn">STRUCTURE</button>
  <button id="surface-btn" class="mobile__CTA--btn">SURFACE</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use an arrow function to keep btn reference into the event listener :

```js
const callToActionBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.mobile__CTA--btn');

callToActionBtns.forEach((btn, _, AllBtn) =>
  {
  btn.onclick = e =>
    {
    if ( btn.classList.toggle('active'))
    AllBtn.forEach( btx => btx.classList.toggle('active', btx===btn ))
    }
  })
```

```css
.active {
  color          : white;
  border-bottom  : 5px solid $purple;
  padding-bottom : 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile__CTA">
  <button id="overview-btn"  class="mobile__CTA--btn"> OVERVIEW </button>
  <button id="structure-btn" class="mobile__CTA--btn"> STRUCTURE </button>
  <button id="surface-btn"   class="mobile__CTA--btn"> SURFACE   </button>
</div>
```